# How to use 'curl' to call a secure (https) WCF service - GET request only

Tags: wcf, ssl, curl, tls1.2

The context is i created a WCF Service, hosted in IIS using https.

I have no issues with the WCF Service itself, it is working as it should; I can navigate to the service page at 
https://myhost/VirtualAppOnIIS/Some/WCF/Service/Here/V1
using a Browser (IE in my case).

The "lock" symbol displays ok, and i can view the certificate info; More cert info is:

- root CA is Verisign, which issued a Verisign Intermediate cert, which issued 
  my server cert (let's call it "myhost")
- "Key Usage" set as critical, purposes are: Digital Signature, Non-Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment (f0)
- The "Extended Key Usage" is absent, so i can conclude it is undefined / not set by the certificate issuer (and therefore this cert can be used as both Server cert or Client cert)

So far so good. My real issue is how to get curl to make a /GET https request (similar to the way the Browser does it).

**Attempt #1.**

> curl --tlsv1.2 https://myhost/VirtualAppOnIIS/Some/WCF/Service/Here/V1 -v

```
*   Trying 192.168.1.114...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to myhost (192.168.1.114) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\SETUPS\curl\curl-ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unsupported certificate purpose
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1): curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unsupported certificate purpose 
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html 
...etc ... 
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use  the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

We can see an error after server hello (2):

> SSL certificate problem: unsupported certificate purpose

I made sure I have both certificates for Intermediate and Root CA concatenated within the file curl-ca-bundle.crt (and nothing else), which curl finds by default, and i don't believe it's a chain validation issue, seems a cert purpose problem as suggested by the error message.

**Attempt #2**

Bybass https validation, as suggested by the curl output, using the -k switch. Yes, it works !

> curl --tlsv1.2 https://myhost/VirtualAppOnIIS/Some/WCF/Service/Here/V1 -v -k

```
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=country; ST=state; O=Some Company PTY LIMITED; CN=myhost
*  start date: Apr 26 00:00:00 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 29 23:59:59 2019 GMT
*  issuer: O=VeriSign; OU=Whatever PKI; CN=Whatever Intermediate CA
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
 GET /VirtualAppOnIIS/Some/WCF/Service/Here/V1 HTTP/1.1
 Host: myhost
 User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
 Accept: */*

 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Cache-Control: private
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
 Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=iy1s4q1hwkncywi5m0w0coch; path=/; HttpOnly
 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 Date: Wed, 02 May 2018 07:08:30 GMT
 Content-Length: 3236

<HTML><HEAD>
etc... etc... more html for wcf service page... etc ... etc...
</BODY></HTML>
 Connection #0 to host myhost left intact
```

So to re-phrase the question, if it is a cert. purpose issue (as suggested in attempt #1), what cert. purposes or settings or configurations are required (when issuing the cert) to make curl and WCF with TLS work ?

Incidentally i am using curl on Windows from https://winampplugins.co.uk/curl/

Comment: when you use `--tlsv1.2`, you force curl to exclusively use tls 1.2. my best guess is that your iis server doesn't support TLS 1.2. try `--tlsv1` instead, and curl will use any tls 1.* version (maybe your IIS server doesn't support TLS higher than 1.1?)

Comment: Yes my server does support TLS 1.2... see attempt #2 output.. it clearly establishes a connection after the TLS handshake messages "SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384"; Furthermore, when pointing a Browser to the WCF-service URL, it informs that the connection is "TLS 1.2, AES with 128 bit encryption (High); ECDH with 255 bit exchange"